# Is the use of Nylon in satellites a bad idea?

Tags: materials

I came across a video of someone from Northrop Grumman talking about how they don't use Nylon in satellites anymore as it accumulates charge which leads to arcing (

).

I tried finding more information about this but can't understand why Nylon behaves this way, nor any information/papers which show any data.

It would be great if anyone could share any resources which provide more insights into this and possible mitigation strategies.

Thank you.

Comment: Lots of plastics accumulate charge and will arc. Basically all insulators (and nylon is an insulator) will do so. So you need to find materials that bleed off charge controllably.